# Copy column between tables in Enterprise Architect

Tags: database, enterprise-architect

I use Enterprise Architect to model database.
Often I have the column in tables (CreateDate, CreateUserId etc), but I don't know how can I copy some columns from one table to second table?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's actually possible, although not obvious.
Open your diagram, expand the table you want to copy from in Project Browser, then you will see all the attributes (columns) of the table. Select one or multiple and drag them to the destination table on the diagram! If you drag them to destination table in Project Browser you will move the columns instead.

Comment: This is indeed not obvious, so +1

Comment: This method works for any attribute or operation, not only for columns.

Comment: This is great! Wish I had known about this earlier.